# Regex matching keys in a Dictionary

Tags: c#, regex, hash-map

I have extended this class http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CSharpMessenger_Extended to accept strings containing wildcards as `eventTypes`, therefore I am able to write things like

```
Messenger.AddListener("*", () => Console.WriteLine("woohoo, generic handler"));
```

But I am highly concerned about the performance of this implementation.

I've extended the Dictionary class like this:

```
public class EventDictionary : Dictionary<string, Delegate>
    {
        public Delegate[] GetHandlers(string Event)
        {
            List<Delegate> matches = new List<Delegate>();
            foreach (string pattern in Keys)
                if (Regex.IsMatch(Event, Regex.Escape(pattern).Replace( @"\*", ".*" ).Replace( @"\?", "." )))
                    matches.Add(this[pattern]);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(matches.Count);
            return matches.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

As you see, for every key in the dictionary, I first convert it to a regular expression, then check if it is a match for the event name, if it's so, add it to a collection and return the array.

But, this code runs in a game where the messenger script is used frequently, therefore I am really concerned about the performance of this approach.

I think storing regex's directly in the dictionary would be better but my main concern is about the regex matching.

Is my solution acceptable? If not what would be a better approach for solving my problem?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! That is an interesting situation, I hope you get some good reviews!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some problems I see with your code:

- The code removes the `Dictionary`'s constant-time lookup.
- The code reparses the pattern and recompiles each regex every time you're
  in the loop.
- The code uses regex's even for simple lookups.
- The code will die if you try to assign more than one handler to an event.
- This might just be an artifact of you copying/pasting, but the indenting on your method is a little unusual.
- The code does not favor [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).
- Your parameter name does not follow the convention of being camelCase.
- Your regex pattern doesn't require the beginning and ends, so e.g. `as?f` matches the same things as `*as?f*`.

I would use the built-in `Dictionary` lookup functionality for simple (no-wildcard) lookups and store compiled regex's for the ones with wildcards. Also, you can look at [the reference source in your link](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CSharpMessenger_Extended) to get an idea of how to solve the problem of multiple handlers for an event.

This should be a good starting point, with code to add a listener and get handlers. It only uses regex's when needed, keeping them precompiled in a second `Dictionary`. If the `"*"` case is pretty common, you could further improve this by handling that as a special case: you don't really need to compile and store a `Regex` for it, you just always run it. This would probably be a third field, maybe `private Delegate universalHandlers;`

```
public class EventDictionary
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Delegate> eventTable = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Regex> regexTable = new Dictionary<string, Regex>();

    private bool HasWildcards(string pattern)
    {
        return pattern.Contains("*") || pattern.Contains("?");
    }

    public void AddListener(string eventType, Delegate eventDelegate)
    {
        Delegate currentDelegate;
        if (eventTable.TryGetValue(eventType, out currentDelegate))
        {
            var d = eventTable[eventType];
            if (d != null && d.GetType() != eventDelegate.GetType())
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Attempting to add listener with inconsistent signature for event type {0}. Current listeners have type {1} and listener being added has type {2}", eventType, d.GetType().Name, eventType.GetType().Name));
            eventTable[eventType] = Delegate.Combine(currentDelegate, eventDelegate);
        }
        else
        {
            eventTable.Add(eventType, eventDelegate);
        }

        if (HasWildcards(eventType) && !regexTable.ContainsKey(eventType))
            regexTable.Add(eventType, new Regex("^" + Regex.Escape(eventType).Replace(@"\*", ".*").Replace(@"\?", ".") + "$"));
    }

    // TODO implement remove method

    public Delegate GetHandlers(string eventType)
    {
        Delegate handler;
        eventTable.TryGetValue(eventType, out handler);
        foreach (var pair in regexTable)
            if (pair.Value.IsMatch(eventType))
                handler = Delegate.Combine(handler, eventTable[pair.Key]);
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(handler.GetInvocationList().Length);
        return handler;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty good and comprehensive. I understand everything but why my code was going to die if I attached 2 listeners to an event. Indentation is due to copy/paste you are right.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR As I understand it, you were going to attach listeners like `eventDictionary.Add("someEvent", myDelegate)`. A `Dictionary<,>` can only hold one value for each key, so this will throw an error on the 2nd listener. If you were just swapping out the `Dictionary` class used in `MessengerInternal` with your class, then you were fine in that regard. My example basically replaces the whole `Messenger` class. You can choose how to best piece these things together.